# Flask custom form in home Tab with custom action

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-admin

I'd like to visualize a form in home/admin page that allows users to select a value from a list (values belongs to a db table) and a button to execute a custom python method.

I am not able to understand if it's possibile to show a form without showing  data of if it's possible to run code without flask-admin.

P.s. the same (simple) code that I use to create a form (just 2 datepickers) in Flask works but as soon as I put it in /home/admin the html and flask-admin cannot talk (exchange the values in the form) anymore.

Update:

This is part of my Flask-admin code:

```
class ExampleForm(Form):
   dt_start = DateField('DatePicker', format='%Y-%m-%d')
   dt_end = DateField('DatePicker', format='%Y-%m-%d')

@app.route('/admin', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
   form = ExampleForm()
   if form.validate_on_submit():
       print("Start date: ", form.dt_start.data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
       print("End date: ", form.dt_end.data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
       return "Form is OK!"
   return render_template('admin/index.html', form=form)
```

HTML CODE:

```
{% extends "admin/master.html" %}

{% block body %}
 <head>
   <title>Download form</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
   <div class="container">
     <h1>Please insert the dates</h1>
     <br>
       <form action="#" method="post">
         {{ form.dt_start(class='datepicker') }}
         {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
         {{ form.dt_end(class='datepicker') }}
         {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
         <input type="submit"/>
         </form>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

ERROR:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

Thanks a lot

Alessandro

Comment: Can you provide what you've tried so far?

Comment: Are you mixing flask-admin and your own version of an admin page?. If yes then there is a BaseView class already present you need to override that and add custom logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer!

"Are you mixing flask-admin and your own version of an admin page?" Yes, exactly!

"If yes then there is a BaseView class already present you need to override that and add custom logic." do you know where I can find an example? 

Thanks a lot again!